# Passing result of requery as parameter to UDF

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to execute a UDF within a query statement and its parameter depends on the current row in the larger query. I need to get a scalar from another table and pass that to the UDF however I get syntax errors if I try to use a query within the parameters of a UDF.

Example:

```
SELECT M.Col1 
FROM MyTable M 
WHERE M.RemoteID = UDFLookupRemoteID(SELECT W.Name 
                               FROM WidgetNames W 
                               WHERE W.Col2 = M.RemoteID)
```

The select within the UDF cannot be done elsewhere since it depends on the outer query.

What's the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Can you give us the definition of the function? I deleted my answer as using a scalar UDF that accesses data in a `WHERE` clause will lead to truly horrible performance. It will be much better to make the logic inline.

Comment: The function belongs to an external library for which I don't have permission to publish the definition unfortunately. However the function itself does not access any tables. It just processes the parameter.

Comment: Ah that's not as bad then. I thought from the name that it was looking up something from a table (which wouldn't be good to do for each individual row in your `M` table.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will give you what you need.

```
SELECT m.col1 
FROM   mytable m 
       INNER JOIN widgetnames w 
         ON w.col2 = m.remoteid 
WHERE  m.remoteid = Udflookupremoteid(w.name)
```

Here's an example I tested with the AdventureWorks database

```
SELECT pr.* 
FROM   production.productreview pr 
       INNER JOIN production.product p 
         ON p.productid = pr.productid 
WHERE  pr.rating < dbo.Ufngetstock(p.productid)
```

Comment: Actually I did try something similar and got a syntax error near '.'

Comment: @nuit9 - Did you try with the function schema qualified (i.e. `dbo.UDFLookupRemoteID`) sometimes (or maybe always actually) SQL Server requires this.

Comment: Yes. The server doesn't seem to have a problem finding the UDF, it just doesn't seem to like using a column name as the parameter.

Comment: @nuit9 maybe you should try this as a sanity check  `SELECT dbo.Udflookupremoteid(w.name) FROM widgetnames w`

Comment: In the sanity check SQL Server intepreted w.name as a table hints option.

Comment: @nuit9 - What version are you on? What compatibility level is your database set to?

Comment: The compatability level is set to 80. Unfortunately I cannot change it to a higher version since some of the legacy code breaks in that case.

Comment: @nuit9 - And what version are you on? In SS2008 even against a db with compat 80 the following worked for me. `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Foo (@p int) RETURNS int AS BEGIN RETURN @p END GO SELECT dbo.Foo(w.object_id) FROM sys.columns w`